Transfer tokens to and from a program
I have a question about linking a wallet to a smart contract. Specifically, I want to send tokens to a program wallet and then have that wallet send tokens to another recipient in a subsequent instruction.
For security reasons, I don't think it's advisable to include the wallet account in each instruction due to the risk associated with exposing the private key, although I could be mistaken.
If this isn't feasible, is it possible to embed the private key within the smart contract or specify it during deployment, and would it be possible to update the smart contract later if needed?
Thank you.

This can easily be done using a PDA (meaning no need for a private key) and a CPI to the token program. I've written a simple example below where we have an instruction for transferring an amount into the ownership of the program and an instruction and one for transferring it out somewhere else:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{Mint, Token, TokenAccount};
declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod non_custodial_escrow {
    use super::*;
    pub fn transfer_in(ctx: Context<TransferIn>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        anchor_spl::token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                anchor_spl::token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.sender_ata.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.escrow_ata.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.sender.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            amount,
        )?;
        ctx.accounts.escrow.bump = ctx.bumps.escrow;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn transfer_out(ctx: Context<TransferOut>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        anchor_spl::token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                anchor_spl::token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.escrow_ata.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.recipient_ata.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.escrow.to_account_info(),
                },
                &[&["escrow".as_bytes(), ctx.accounts.sender.key().as_ref(), &[ctx.accounts.escrow.bump]]],
            ),
            amount,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferIn<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    sender: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, constraint = sender_ata.mint == mint.key() && sender_ata.owner == sender.key())] 
    sender_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        init, 
        payer = sender,
        // For the discriminator and bump
        space= 9,
        seeds = ["escrow".as_bytes(), sender.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub escrow: Account<'info, Escrow>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = sender,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = escrow,
    )]
    escrow_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


#[account]
pub struct Escrow {
    bump :u8,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferOut<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    recipient: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, constraint = recipient_ata.mint == mint.key() && recipient_ata.owner == recipient.key())] 
    recipient_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    /// CHECK: Sender who deposited the tokens
    sender : AccountInfo<'info>,
    mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["escrow".as_bytes(), sender.key().as_ref()],
        bump = escrow.bump,
    )]
    pub escrow: Account<'info, Escrow>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint = escrow_ata.mint == mint.key() && escrow_ata.owner == escrow.key(),
    )]
    escrow_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

I assume in your case you probably also want some more complex unlock logic, I can recommend the escrow program example from the anchor docs for this as a next step once the code in my answer makes sense to you.

Thank you again for your answer Ahri!
If I understand it correctly, the one who created the first transfer also created the escrow account. So it's related to his usage no?
I'm trying to buy an item for a specific amount with a wallet, but someone can rebuy it and reimburse the item's previous owner. But all transactions gone to the program wallet that I can manage with Trust wallet or solfare or anything else.
